# Unable to select Checkbox in Angular UI Grid using selenium

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, angular-ui-grid

I am automating a web application where angular UI Grid is used for showing up the data,I want  to select checkbox in the Grid by row  using selenium But not able to achieve the task,Anything out there can u help with these...

**MY HTML Code:**

```
<div class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope"
     ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" 
     ng-click="selectButtonClick(row, $event)" 
     role="button" 
     tabindex="0"
>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code to click on check box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select `checkbox` in the Grid you can use the following line of code :

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope']"))).Click();
```